# Issues Fitting Generated Table to Width

Tags: tables

I have reviewed quite a few posts on here, yet everything seems to be breaking my table, so I figured I'd just post my probem and ask for help. I generated a table using https://www.tablesgenerator.com

I am having issues fitting my table to the width of the page without shrinking the text:

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
      \begin{table}[]
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccc}
        \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
        \multicolumn{13}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Title}} \\ \hline
        \textit{\textbf{Hashtag}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
        {\textit{\textbf{Service1}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
        {\textit{\textbf{Service2}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
        {\textit{\textbf{Service3}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
        {\textit{\textbf{Service4}}} \\ \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
          \textit{} & \textit{True} & \textit{False} & \textit{Accuracy} & 
          \textit{True} & \textit{False} & \textit{Accuracy} & \textit{True} & 
          \textit{False} & \textit{Accuracy} & \textit{True} & \textit{False} & 
          \textit{Accuracy} \\ \hline
          \textit{\#1} & n & n & n\% & x & x & x & n & n & n\% & n & 
           n & n\% \\ \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
          \textit{\#2} & n & n & n\% & x & x & x & n & n & n\% & n & 
           n & n\% \\ \hline
          \textit{\#3} & n & n & n\% & x & x & x & n & n & n\% & n & 
           n & n\% \\ \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
          \textit{\#4} & n & n & n\% & x & x & x & n& 100 & n\% & n
          & n & n\% \\ \hline
          \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\#5, \\ \#6, \\ \#7\end{tabular} & n & n & 
          n\% & n & n & n\% & n & n & n\% & n & n & n\% \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}%
      }
 \end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two more possible solutions using a smaller `\tabcolsep` or abbreviated column headers:

[image]

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

      \begin{table}
      \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
        \begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccc}
        \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
        \multicolumn{13}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Title}} \\ \hline
        \textit{\textbf{Hashtag}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
        {\textit{\textbf{Service1}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
        {\textit{\textbf{Service2}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
        {\textit{\textbf{Service3}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
        {\textit{\textbf{Service4}}} \\ \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
          \textit{} & \textit{True} & \textit{False} & \textit{Acc.} & 
          \textit{True} & \textit{False} & \textit{Acc.} & \textit{True} & 
          \textit{False} & \textit{Accuracy} & \textit{True} & \textit{False} & 
          \textit{Acc.} \\ \hline
          \textit{\#1} & n & n & n\% & x & x & x & n & n & n\% & n & 
           n & n\% \\ \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
          \textit{\#2} & n & n & n\% & x & x & x & n & n & n\% & n & 
           n & n\% \\ \hline
          \textit{\#3} & n & n & n\% & x & x & x & n & n & n\% & n & 
           n & n\% \\ \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
          \textit{\#4} & n & n & n\% & x & x & x & n& 100 & n\% & n
          & n & n\% \\ \hline
        \#5  &&&&&&&&&&&&\\                   
        \#6, & n & n & 
          n\% & n & n & n\% & n & n & n\% & n & n & n\% \\ 
        \#7  &&&&&&&&&&&&\\   
          \hline
          \end{tabular}
 \end{table}


      \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccc}
        \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
        \multicolumn{13}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Title}} \\ \hline
        \textit{\textbf{Hashtag}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
        {\textit{\textbf{Service1}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
        {\textit{\textbf{Service2}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
        {\textit{\textbf{Service3}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
        {\textit{\textbf{Service4}}} \\ \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
          \textit{} & \textit{T} & \textit{F} & \textit{Acc.} & 
          \textit{T} & \textit{F} & \textit{Acc.} & \textit{T} & 
          \textit{F} & \textit{Acc.} & \textit{T} & \textit{F} & 
          \textit{Acc.} \\ \hline
          \textit{\#1} & n & n & n\% & x & x & x & n & n & n\% & n & 
           n & n\% \\ \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
          \textit{\#2} & n & n & n\% & x & x & x & n & n & n\% & n & 
           n & n\% \\ \hline
          \textit{\#3} & n & n & n\% & x & x & x & n & n & n\% & n & 
           n & n\% \\ \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
          \textit{\#4} & n & n & n\% & x & x & x & n& 100 & n\% & n
          & n & n\% \\ \hline
          \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\#5, \\ \#6, \\ \#7\end{tabular} & n & n & 
          n\% & n & n & n\% & n & n & n\% & n & n & n\% \\ \hline
          \multicolumn{13}{l}{T: True, F: False, Acc.: Accuracy}
      \end{tabular}%
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The table has too many columns to fit in the available text width at its normal size, but instead of using `\resizebox` you could manually select a smaller font size, e.g. `\small`, this will give you more appropriate letter shapes for the font size.

In addition you could safe some space by abbreviating some of the long words in the header.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table,xcdraw}{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{showframe}{geometry}
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
 \usepackage{graphicx}


%   \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

      \begin{table}[]
%        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\small
        \begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccc}
        \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
        \multicolumn{13}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Title}} \\ \hline
        \textit{\textbf{Hashtag}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
        {\textit{\textbf{Service1}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
        {\textit{\textbf{Service2}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
        {\textit{\textbf{Service3}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
        {\textit{\textbf{Service4}}} \\ \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
          \textit{} & \textit{True} & \textit{False} & \textit{Acc.} & 
          \textit{True} & \textit{False} & \textit{Acc.} & \textit{True} & 
          \textit{False} & \textit{Accuracy} & \textit{True} & \textit{False} & 
          \textit{Acc.} \\ \hline
          \textit{\#1} & n & n & n\% & x & x & x & n & n & n\% & n & 
           n & n\% \\ \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
          \textit{\#2} & n & n & n\% & x & x & x & n & n & n\% & n & 
           n & n\% \\ \hline
          \textit{\#3} & n & n & n\% & x & x & x & n & n & n\% & n & 
           n & n\% \\ \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
          \textit{\#4} & n & n & n\% & x & x & x & n& 100 & n\% & n
          & n & n\% \\ \hline
        \#5  &&&&&&&&&&&&\\                   
        \#6, & n & n & 
          n\% & n & n & n\% & n & n & n\% & n & n & n\% \\ 
        \#7  &&&&&&&&&&&&\\   
          \hline
      \end{tabular}%
%      }
 \end{table}

 \end{document}
```